# Fatal Error loading the resource file: java.io.EFOException Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have an error within my project. I'm not sure what happened but I was working on my app and all of a sudden the Theme.res file stopped working. When I try to access the Theme.res file, I receive an error saying

> Fatal Error loading the resource file: java.io.EFOException

When I run the project the console output displays this:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,17 - Exception: java.io.EOFException - null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:281)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:269)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:189)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:740)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:702)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:666)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initFirstTheme(UIManager.java:1551)
    at com.prestonwhite.productionpumpapp.Run.init(Run.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:117)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1056)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:873)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prestonwhite.productionpumpapp.Run.init(Run.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:117)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1056)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:873)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Java Result: 1
```

I don't know what happened because everything was running fine and then all of a sudden this error randomly occurred. What can I do to fix this problem? Can I restore/recover my Theme.res file?

Note: I am using Netbeans on Windows 7.

Comment: P.s. Could the problem be because of the last Codename One plugin update? I'm asking because my project worked fine before the update but after I updated the libraries, it stopped working.

Comment: This is a problem with the resource file. Check that the res file is not 0 size. In the designer tool if you are using XML team mode check the output when you try to save using the instructions here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html